# Is this sentence understandable? "Gained the most points every round in 50+ games"

Tags: sentence, writing-style

I'm writing some in-game descriptions for various challenges. 
One of the challenges is to win 50 games, whilst also having the most points in every round of said games.

I arrived at this formulation:

> Gained the most points every round in 50+ games.

Do you think it is clear and understandable?

EDIT 1: It's possible to win a game even if you don't earn the most points in all rounds. There are four rounds in a single game and the player who wins the most rounds takes the prize.

EDIT 2: These don't have to be consecutive games.

Comment: So you can win without the most points?

Comment: Seconding marcello's query: is there a way to win a game without having the most points? (Edit: on reflection it seems like a game is made up of multiple rounds, so you can win a game on rounds while still losing at least one round on points)

Comment: @marcellothearcane yes, the winner of the game is determined by who won the most rounds (there are four rounds in total). The winner in each round is determined by points earned only during that round.

Comment: So you could simply say 'you won 50+ games in a row', since the winner would have the most points.

Comment: @marcellothearcane The challenge is to win 50+ games where you were the highest scorer in all four rounds of each of those games. If you beat me in 50 games but I'd won a single round in game 24 you wouldn't meet the criteria.

Comment: @SīmanisMikoss It may help if you specify in the body of your question what your specific concern is with the wording as you currently have it, given that someone has voted to close it for being an off-topic proofreading question.

Comment: It's comprehensible eventually, but it's not immediately clear.  I think a better formulation would be "win every round in at least 50 games."

Comment: Technically, since it has no subject, it's actually only a sentence fragment. But in the context of a list of accomplishments (rather than something standalone), it's fine.

Comment: @SīmanisMikoss I personally feel this needs to be rephrased as *Gained the most points **in** every round **of** 50+ games.* That would help clear up at least some of the confusion over what is meant.

Comment: @marcellothearcane My understanding is that it's a bit like winning a tennis match in straight sets or winning a match play golf competition without dropping a hole. Perhaps the OP could confirm or refute my analogy?

Comment: @BoldBen I'm not too strong in sports' terminology, but the comparison seems to be correct.

Comment: @SīmanisMikoss The tennis one is a bit difficult to explain but there are two types of golf match: "stroke play" where the total number of strokes is counted and "match play" where the number of holes won is counted. In match play it would be possible to lose eight holes by big margins, win ten holes by small margins and win the match by two holes but actually take more strokes overall. If you lose a hole in match play you would have "dropped a hole" even though you won the match. If you take all eighteen holes that seems to me like the situation you described in the question.

Comment: (s)he has won 50+ games earning the most points in every single round.

Answer (score 0):

Gained the most points every round in 50+ games.

I think your familiarity with the games and the challenges is allowing you to write in an increasingly compact form. Your perspective has shifted with your expertise. You are aware of this since you are asking for outside views.

With some effort and your clarifications I and others here can work it out. Unless you are short of type face for printing I suggest you use at least two, perhaps three sentences to say the same thing. There can be little reason not to.

I am still a fan of the outline where you describe the thing, what it's got and what it does. With that in mind you should have no trouble making a perfectly clear description. There are no points or bonuses for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Two valid suggestions were offered by Hellion and Jason Bassford:

- Win every round in at least 50 games
- Gained the most points in every
  round of 50+ games

I believe both of these answers are easier to understand than the one originally proposed by me.

The requirements for the description of the challenge changed completely, and so did the formulation, hence I will be closing the discussion (once I figure out how).

This was my first post here, so I'm not 100% sure whether it falls under acceptable questions, but I'm glad for your feedback.